# Inverse square law: sphere - point equivalence

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates, symmetry

Let's assume we are dealing with gravity. The gravitational field of a uniform sphere with some mass will only depend on the mass and the distance away from the center of the sphere $R$ (assuming $R$ is outside of the sphere). I want to derive this fact by investigating a spherical shell and showing its gravitational field is equivalent to having all the mass concentrated in the center without using non-obvious facts like Gauss' law.

In other words, I want to show that the following integral is invariant wrt. $r$, the radius of the spherical shell; and inversely proportional to $R^2$ if $R>r$ and zero if $R<r$

$$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{\pi}_{0}\frac{R-r\cos\theta}{\left(\sqrt{R-r \cos\theta)^2+(r\sin\theta\cos\phi)^2+(r\sin\theta\sin\phi)^2}\right)^3}\sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi$$

Where the point for which we calculate the field is assumed to be on the $+z$ axis, $\theta$ is the angle made with $z$ axis, $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle on the $xy$ plane.

Seems like a very difficult integral to solve naively. I would love if there are intuitive explanations for this fact, maybe using symmetry etc.

Comment: How did you get that integral?

Comment: Thank you @Ian, I read a bit too fast

Comment: Note that your integral as it is is not the end of the story, because you also need to integrate $dr$.

Comment: @Ian I think the solution for that is intuitively very straightforward. if an arbitrary spherical shell is equivalent to the mass being concentrated at the center, then all the spherical shells with varying radii can also be concentrated at the origin. In other words, the 3D integral can be separated into a 2D integral (one I have shown) which proves this fact (difficult to me), and a 1D integral that calculates the total mass of the spherical shells (easy to me)

Comment: Yeah I guess if each shell produces an infinitesimal force and all of these infinitesimal forces are parallel then it's straightforward enough to sum them up.